# Kendo Window pinned does not seem to work

Tags: kendo-ui

The web page is simple, and I have a kendo window, which I show right away at document ready, but no matter what I do, the window is not pinned. I would like the window to be fixed on the screen and let content roll underneath it.

I have not used Kendo much, but would like to do so for a couple of projects.

Any insights on what I am missing?

```
$(document).ready(function( event ) { 

var window = $("#add-comment");

window.kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    height: "315px",
    position: {
            top: 100,
            left: 100
        },        
    title: "Add Comment",
    modal: true,
    pinned: true,
    visible: true,
    actions: ["Maximize", "Close"],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `pinned` is in the documentation [`here`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#configuration-pinned) it is not in the latest release of code (v2013.1.514). Hopefully any time soon. Maybe this time they updated the documentation sooner than the code :-)

In the meantime, you can get it by defining a CSS style as this:

```
.ob-pinned {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

And adding the following piece of code (compatible with your initialization):

```
win = $("#add-comment").data("kendoWindow");
if (win.options.pinned) {
    win.wrapper.addClass("ob-pinned")
               .css("top", win.options.position.top)
               .css("left", win.options.position.left);
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/dcPex/